# Asset Catalog UIImage ImageNamed: was nil

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, asset-catalog

I have 2 Assets Catalogs in my App. One is in the Source Directory of my App and the other one is linked to my Project and Target Membership was set.

When i would load an image from the Linked Assetscatalog with

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_close"];
```

the Image was nil

when i load an image form the Asset Catalog in the Sourc Directory it would be loaded

can someone help me i have no idea why the image is not loaded.

In old Projects it would be work fine but when i Create a Project with Xcode 6 it dose not work.

Comment: see that each asset catalog has only one target.

Comment: each asset catalog has only the target Membership of my Project Target

Comment: @Zeropointer were you able to get a solution to this?

Comment: @Shwethascar no sry my solution for now was to add the Linked Asset Catalog fix to the Project